# Background job support in Spring

Tags: java, spring, background-process

I am looking for support from Spring to execute background jobs. I want to trigger the jobs from my application and run in the background without hampering the execution of the application. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See link from hasnae above. In Java Config you can do something like:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class BackgroundTaskScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private BackgroundTaskBean backgroundTaskBean;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${property.cronStatement}")
    public void backgroundTaskOne() {
        backgroundTaskBean.runTask();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

see spring [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)